# For some reason, my table is cut off when it used to run before

Tags: tables

EDIT:

```
\documentclass[11pt,leqno]{article}
\usepackage[top=1.0in,bottom=1.0in,left=0.8in,right=0.8in]{geometry}
\addtolength{\skip\footins}{1pc plus 1pt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand{\scell}[1]{{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{theorem}}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand{\header}[1]{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}%
}
\newcommand{\theader}[1]{\smash{\header{#1}}}

\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{S}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{D}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{o}{@{}>{{}}c<{{}}@{}}
\usepackage{textcmds}
\usepackage{longtable}
\newcommand{\scell}[2][c]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\scelll}[2][l]{%
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}l@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\xsub}[1]{%
  \mbox{\scriptsize\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}%
}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[all]{nowidow}
\usepackage{euscript}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{float}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{./figures/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont={small},
labelsep=period,justification=centering,
font={small},skip=6pt}


\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\fontsize{20pt}{22pt}\selectfont\bf}{ }{40pt}{\thechapter. \raggedright}[]

\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]
  {\fontsize{22pt}{22pt}\selectfont\bf}{}{0pt}{
  \fontsize{15pt}{16pt}\selectfont\raggedright}[]

\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing{name=\chapter,numberless}{0pt}{-20pt}{30pt}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\fontsize{16pt}{17pt}
\bfseries\raggedright}{\thesection}{0.2em}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pc}{*5.6}{*1.7}[0pc]

%
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{14pt}{15pt}\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{0.3em}{}

\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pc}{*2.6}{*1.7}[0pc]

\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\normalfont\fontsize{12}{14}\bfseries}{\thesubsubsection}{0.3em}{}

\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}
{0pc}{*2.6}{*1.7}[0pc]

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin*{table}{section}
\counterwithin*{equation}{section}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\arabic{subsubsection}.}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thesection\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection\arabic{table}}

\makeatletter
 \def\@maketitle{%
 \newpage
 \null
 \vskip 2em%
 \begin{center}%
 \let \footnote \thanks
 {\LARGE\bf \@title \par}%
 \vskip 1.5em%
 {\large
  \lineskip .5em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
  \@author
  \end{tabular}\par}%
 %\vskip 1em%
 %{\large \@date}%
 \end{center}%
 \par
 \vskip 1.5em}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\erfc}{\operatorname{erfc}}
\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}
\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}
\newcommand{\ce}{\operatorname{ce}}
```

My table code is:

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\tabcolsep=1.0\tabcolsep
\begin{table}[t!]\small
\caption{Tests of Hypotheses\textsuperscript{1}}
\label{t31}
\begin{tabular}{lL{60mm}S{18mm}
S{25mm}S{20mm}S{12mm}}\hline
&Tested Hypothesis &
Maintained Hypothesis&
Assigned Level of Significance
& Number of Restrictions
&$p$-value \\ \hline
%
I. &Maintained Hypotheses of the
Meta-production Function Approach
& &  &&  \\ \hline
&Single Meta-Production Function
\& Commodity Augmentation
& Unrestricted & 0.01 & 50 & 1.00002
\\ \hline
II. &Traditionally Maintained Hypotheses &&&&\\ \hline
&(1a) Homogeneity
%
&I&0.005&3&.00000\\\hline
&(1b) Constant Returns to Scale &       I+II(1a) & 0.005 & 1 & .21595 \\ \hline
&(2) Neutrality &I&0.01&42&.00115 \\\hline
&(3) Profit Maximization &I&0.01& 35 & .00000 \\ \hline
%
III. &Hypotheses on Intangible Inputs&&&&  \\ \hline
&(1) No Human Capital Effect &             I & 0.01 & 4 & .00000 \\ \hline
&(2) No Technical Progress &
I & 0.01 & 56 & .00000 \\ \hline
%
IV. &Hypotheses on Augmentation Levels
& & &  &  \\ \hline
&(1) Identical Augmentation
Levels for Tangible Capital
&I& 0.005 & 6 & .13854 \\ \hline
&(2) Identical Augmentation Levels for Labor
&I & 0.005 & 6 & .94335 \\ \hline
& (3) Identical Augmentation Levels for Human Capital
&I & 0.005 & 6 & .54661 \\ \hline
%
V. &Hypotheses on Augmentation Rates
&&&& \\ \hline
&(1) Purely Output-Augmenting\textsuperscript{3}
&I & 0.01 & 42 & .00115 \\ \hline
&(2) Purely Tangible Capital-Augmenting&     I& 0.005 & 42 & .01659 \\ \hline
&(3) Purely Labor-Augmenting &             I & 0.005 & 42 & .00277 \\ \hline
&(4) Purely Human Capital-Augmenting&        I & 0.005 & 42 & .15363 \\ \hline
%
VI. &Test of No Oil Price Effect (1974-1985)  & I & 0.01 & 28 & .01255 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}\medskip
\raggedright

{\small Notes:}
\begin{enumerate}[itemsep=0pt,
before={\fontsize{9pt}{9pt}\selectfont},label=\arabic*]
 \item The variance-covariance matrix is updated successively at the non-identical production function and identical production function and commodity-augmentation stages and fixed thereafter.
\item Due to rounding.

\item The test for the hypothesis of purely output-augmenting technical progress is identical with the test for that of neutrality.
\end{enumerate}
\end{table}
}
```

For some reason, the output looks like:

[image: why is this the case?]

Why is this the case?

Thank you!

Comment: In summary, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and not only the code for table. Moreover, why what? The width of the table? The horrible horizontal lines in every row? The odd  centering of the second column? Please explain.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of deleting a code chunk that originated from my initial answer, which I've completely rewritten in the meantime.

Answer (score 4):

(I rewrote the answer completely after the OP posted what appears to be the preamble of a document.)

You wrote,

> For some reason, the output looks like [this] ... Why is this the case?

It looks like your document's preamble contains code that defines a column type named `S`; in particular, this definition appears to be used in the construction of the table. Then, more recently, it would appear that you took to loading the `siunitx` package. Now it so happens that the `siunitx` package *also* defines a column type named `S`. Moreover, given the loading sequence within the preamble, the `siunitx` version of the `S` column type overwrites your definition. That's the immediate reason for why the table's output is no longer what you want it to be.

Incidentally, the screenshot of the table you posted could only have been generated by telling LaTeX to disregard all error and warning messages and to keep compiling. If you had taken a closer look at the log file, you would have noticed that LaTeX was stumbling over the `S` column type.

Assuming that you wish to continue to employ the `siunitx` package -- after all, there was a reason for why you started loading it, right? -- I suggest you choose a different letter than `S` for the column type you wish to employ in your table.

Comment: Hi! 
It did not work for me. The packages I've loaded I've put back on the post in an edit. Thank you!

Comment: @tiffj56 - Please see the complete re-write of my answer.